# Navigate to a router and displaying a different URL in the browser angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Navigating to a router path using router.navigate but display in browser a different URL all together.

Like I want to navigate to below path
this.router.navigate(['/open/quote/']);

but show in browser /quote only without /open.

I already have a route path of /quote which is used for a different purpose in the application

I want to navigate to path /open/reload but in the browser show the path /open/quote. The path /open/quote is having a different resolver so don't want to recall that.

Comment: I would reorganize routing in this case. You can also try router.navigateByUrl('/open/quote/', { skipLocationChange: true });

Comment: Posting your route code would help craft a quality answer specific to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this.router.navigate(['/open/quote/']);` and after navigating to the specific component use `this.location.replaceState('/quote');`

Answer (score -1):

You must define that path in your routing module. 
{ path: 'open/quote', component: YourComponent }